# create log file for some deleted groups in AD

Tags: powershell

I want to delete some groups from AD . I have a list with all groups which will be deleted but i want to create a log for all deleted groups. I have used this command but not work .
get-content d:\file.txt | Remove-ADGroup | out-file d:\log.txt
All groups for my "file " are deleted but log file are not populated with any info .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-adgroup?view=win10-ps#outputs) to see what the output of the commands are that you can capture and save to file.

Since the cmdlet `Remove-ADGroup` has no output, you cannot pipe it to `Out-File`. If you need to capture the output, you will need to use a script block.

```
$content = Get-Content D:\file.txt
$content | % { 
  Write-Output "Deleting $_"
  try {
    Get-ADGroup $_ -ErrorAction Stop
  }
  catch {
    "Group $_ not found."
    return
  }
  Remove-ADGroup $_ -Whatif #-Confirm:$false
  write-output "Group $_ removed successfully."
} | Out-File D:\log.txt -Append
```

Remove `-whatif` once you have confirmed it does what its supposed to do. You can use `-Confirm:$false` to prevent Confirmation requests as well.

Comment: Thank you for you quick replay, your code works correctly , but if I have in my groups list  "D:\file.txt" some groups which don't exist in AD is possible to see this in my log file ? For example group "abc" don't exist or something like this.

Comment: @bogdan09 See the update. Make sure you use -append as well on the Out-file otherwise you'll only have the latest updates and all other data will be overwritten.

Comment: Hello , and thanks again i have tested this code and all works good.

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = Get-Content D:\file.txt
$content | Get-ADGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | foreach {
    try {
        Remove-ADGroup $_ -Confirm:$false
        $_.Name | Out-File d:\log.txt
    }
    catch { }
}
```